# Getting the second childnode with the same class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm currently trying to get "Output" from below

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" data-campaign="Header">
   <li>
      <a data-medium="Menu-KhoaHoc" href="/khoa-hoc" title="Khoa hoc">Khoa hoc</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a data-medium="Menu-TinTuc" href="/khoa-hoc/tin-tuc" title="Tin tuc">Output</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

So far, I only managed to get

```
private static async Task<string> Category(string? url)
    {
        string stringInsert = "";
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var html = new HtmlWeb()
            {
                AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = html.Load(url);
            stringInsert = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").First(item => item.Attributes.Contains("data-campaign") && item.Attributes["data-campaign"].Value == "Header").InnerText;
        });
        return stringInsert;
    }
    //This returns a value of "Khoa hocOutput"
```

I tried using Skip(1).First() but the output is the same. Using ElementAt(1) returns OutOfIndexExeption.

This is my first time working with Html so I dont know anyway to get the desired result. I'm also required to NOT using Xpath in my code

Comment: You already managed to find descendants of the root node based on some criteria. So, basically you already know how you can find descendants of the <ul> node based on some (similar) criteria.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, I leaved my answer here

```
private static async Task<string> Category(string? url)
    {
        string stringInsert = "";
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var html = new HtmlWeb()
            {
                AutoDetectEncoding = false,
                OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = html.Load(url);
            var a = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul")
                        .First(item => item.Attributes.Contains("data-campaign") && item.Attributes["data-campaign"].Value == "Header").ChildNodes;
            stringInsert = a.Descendants("a").Skip(1).First().InnerText;
        });
        return stringInsert;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code may resolve your query.

```
 var stringInsert = DomMain.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attributes["data-medium"].Value == "Menu-TinTuc");
```

[image]